# Method 'loadAceessToken' in protocol 'FHSTwitterEngineAccessTokenDelegate' not implemented

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Please you say how to solve this?

```
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:kOAuthConsumerKey andSecret:kOAuthConsumerSecret];
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];
[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the
`- (NSString *)loadAccessToken;`
and
`- (void)storeAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken;`
methods in your delegate.

I guess that the first method should return the access token that you should store when the second method is called.

```
@protocol FHSTwitterEngineAccessTokenDelegate <NSObject>

- (NSString *)loadAccessToken;
- (void)storeAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken;

@optional
- (void)twitterEngineControllerDidCancel;

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure Quentin Hayot?